# Too many wordpress redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I've inherited a page with a large multi-step form at /big-form that's passing fields to each subsequent step via POST. I need to make each step more SEO friendly, something like /form/step-[1-5]. It would also have /other-form/step-[1-5] on the same page.

I added this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^form/step-[1-5] /big-form/ [QSA,L]
```

which should push requests for the SEO pages to the already created page, but it 404s. Looking through the redirect logs, it's catching the /form/step-1 url, redirecting that to /big-form, *then* doing the usual wordpress redirects through /index.php. For some reason, by the time WordPress is looking for what page to render, it's getting confused and giving up.

Is there a way to redirect all requests from the SEO friendly URLs to the actual page in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the site does not contain any other URLs containing "step", you could just do:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} step

RewriteRule .* /big-form/ [R=301]